# Same Makefile executing different commands in different computers

Tags: makefile, pintos

During installation of pintos, I had to run `make`.

Following is the Makefile.

```
all: setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -W
LDFLAGS = -lm
setitimer-helper: setitimer-helper.o
squish-pty: squish-pty.o
squish-unix: squish-unix.o

clean: 
    rm -f *.o setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix
```

In one computer it executed correctly. (output for the command is given below)

```
gcc -Wall -W   -c -o setitimer-helper.o setitimer-helper.c
gcc -lm  setitimer-helper.o   -o setitimer-helper
gcc -Wall -W   -c -o squish-pty.o squish-pty.c
gcc -lm  squish-pty.o   -o squish-pty
gcc -Wall -W   -c -o squish-unix.o squish-unix.c
gcc -lm  squish-unix.o   -o squish-unix
```

but in other computer I got the following error

```
gcc -lm  setitimer-helper.o   -o setitimer-helper
setitimer-helper.o: In function `main':
setitimer-helper.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `floor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'setitimer-helper' failed
make: *** [setitimer-helper] Error 1
```

If looked at first line of outputs of both `make` commands

```
gcc -Wall -W   -c -o setitimer-helper.o setitimer-helper.c
```

and

```
gcc -lm  setitimer-helper.o   -o setitimer-helper
```

They are different.

Why `make` is executing different commands for the same Makefile? and What should I do to remove error?

Comment: Looks like, in the second computer, some built binaries were already there. Is your working directory a shared partition mounted on both computers? Or did you `make` on the first and then copy everything, including binaries, on the second? Are the two computers identical (same hardware and same installed software)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first computer, the `setitimer-helper.o` file either doesn't exist or the `setitimer-helper.c` file is newer, so make needs to rebuild it.  Thus it runs the compiler, then afterwards it performs the link operation:

```
gcc -Wall -W   -c -o setitimer-helper.o setitimer-helper.c
gcc -lm  setitimer-helper.o   -o setitimer-helper
```

On the second computer, the `setitimer-helper.o` file already exists and is newer than the `setitimer-helper.c` file, so the compile command was not needed and the second computer proceeded directly to the link line:

```
gcc -lm  setitimer-helper.o   -o setitimer-helper
```

The real question is why you got the linker error on the second computer.

The answer to that is that the `-lm` flag needs to come on the linker line *after* the object files.  This happens because you added `-lm` to the `LDFLAGS` variable which is not the right one: that should contain options that tell the linker where to look for files, etc. (for example, the `-L` option).

Libraries should be added to the `LDLIBS` variable, not `LDFLAGS`.  Change your makefile to this:

```
all: setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -W
LDLIBS = -lm
setitimer-helper: setitimer-helper.o
squish-pty: squish-pty.o
squish-unix: squish-unix.o

clean: 
        rm -f *.o setitimer-helper squish-pty squish-unix
```

Your link line will then look like:

```
gcc  setitimer-helper.o   -o setitimer-helper -lm
```

and should work properly.

Comment: Sounds good. Would be even better if you also had an explanation about why `gcc -lm  setitimer-helper.o   -o setitimer-helper` worked on the first computer.

Comment: I can't explain that, at least not with the information provided.